# Changing values with conditional and function in pandas/python

Tags: pandas, numpy, function, loops, iteration

I have a dataframe, as per the table below A. I want to create a table with the values ​​of table B.

I would like to compare the next value in the row with the previous value in table A.

If the next value in the row is EQUAL to the previous value in the row, apply the function (**value*3**) to the next value(j).

If the next value is LESS than the previous one, we keep the same values.

If the next value is HIGHER than the previous one, we keep the same values.

TABLE A:

| Bird1 | Bird2 | Bird3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 50 | 200 |
| 100 | 40 | 100 |
| 100 | 40 | 100 |
| 80 | 80 | 200 |

The result should be as per the table below. How to implement this code in python?

TABLE B:

| Bird1 | Bird2 | Bird3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 50 | 200 |
| **300** | 40 | 100 |
| **900** | **120** | **300** |
| 80 | 80 | 200 |

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Ok, what you say you want seems pretty clear.  So what's your question?  This is a Q & A site.  You need to ask a specific question.  "How to implement this code in python?" is not a valid question.  This isn't a code writing service.  If you have no code yet, you probably won't yet be able to ask a question that belongs on Stack Overflow.  Give the problem a try on your own, and then when you get stuck, add your code to this question and ask a specific question about it.  "please fix this code so it works" is also not an acceptable sort of question here.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
df_out = df.apply(
    lambda x: [
        v := x[0],
        *(v := v * 3 if a - b == 0 else (v := b) for a, b in zip(x, x[1:])),
    ]
)
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
   Bird1  Bird2  Bird3
0    100     50    200
1    300     40    100
2    900    120    300
3     80     80    200
```